# What are some compact (Hausdorff) groups?

Tags: compactness, topological-groups

I just realized today that I don't know any compact groups that aren't profinite groups or Lie groups.

Generalizing from these, a product of compact groups is again a compact group, a closed subgroup of such a product is then again a compact group, and a quotient of such a group by a closed normal subgroup is again a compact group.

So now these are all the examples of compact groups I know.

**What are some interesting and/or counterintuitive examples arising in this fashion? What other compact groups are out there?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You''ve generated all examples. A corollary of the [Peter-Weyl theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem) is that every compact (Hausdorff) group is a closed subgroup of a product of $U(n)$s.

Comment: I remember reading that theorem in books on Lie groups, but somehow I never realized that structure theorem followed. Thanks!

Comment: I think one can make a stronger statement - the category of compact groups might be equivalent to the category of pro-compact Lie groups - but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can (this is from Bourbaki). Pick an open neighborhood $V$ of $1 \in G$. Since the injection $G \to \prod U(n_j)$ is continuous, we can find neighborhoods of $1$ in finitely many of the $U(n_j)$ such that the preimage of their product is in $V$. In particular, the intersection $H$ of the kernels of the projections $G \to U(n_j)$ for these $j$ is closed normal. Then $G/H$ injects into the product of those finitely many $U(n_j)$, and so is a Lie group. Find these closed subgroups $H_m$ for a neighborhood basis $(V_m)$ of $1$ in $G$; then $G$ is the inverse limit of the Lie groups $G/H_m$.

Answer (score 2):

A [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)) is an interesting example that arises as a closed subgroup of a product of circles.

Comment: Cool! Now I'd say that, although I know the structure,I only essentially know three types of examples. But I feel I have to accept Qiaochu Yuan's answer, because that is indeed all of them.  Do you have any more classes of examples?

Comment: @jdc Sorry, nothing else leaps to mind... but I'm hardly an expert, so it's quite likely that there are simple examples that I don't know about!

Comment: @jdc: by Pontryagin duality, all abelian examples arise as Pontryagin duals of discrete abelian groups. Solenoids arise as Pontryagin duals of groups like $\mathbb{Q}$. Profinite abelian groups arise as Pontryagin duals of torsion abelian groups (this is a contravariant equivalence of categories).

Comment: (Cofiltered limits of copies of $S^1$ arise as Pontryagin duals of filtered colimits of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$; these are precisely the torsion-free abelian groups, like $\mathbb{Q}$.)